# delphi form transparency not working in win7

Tags: forms, delphi, transparency

i made small application,

where i have mainform with `form.color := clolive ;`
and have set up `transparentcolor := true;`
and `TransparentColorvalue := clolive;`

it working good on my windows 8.1 without desktop effects.
I can "draw" on `mainform.canvas`

When I tested this mini application on windows 7 with visual styles, form transparency was ignored, i was unable to draw, my mouse cursor "touched" icons and objects "behind" the `mainform`

any ideas how to fix it?

thanks

My code:

```
unit Unit1;

interface

uses
  Windows, Messages, SysUtils, Variants, Classes, Graphics, Controls, Forms,
  Dialogs, StdCtrls;

type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    Button1: TButton;
    Button2: TButton;
    procedure Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
    procedure Button2Click(Sender: TObject);
    procedure FormClick(Sender: TObject);
  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
application.minimize;
end;

procedure TForm1.Button2Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
application.terminate;
end;

procedure TForm1.FormClick(Sender: TObject);
var p: TPoint;
begin
form1.Canvas.Pen.Color:=clyellow;
form1.Canvas.Pen.Width:=5;
p.X:=mouse.CursorPos.X;
p.y:=mouse.CursorPos.Y;
form1.Canvas.PenPos:=p;
form1.Canvas.LineTo(p.x,p.y);
end;

end.
```

form1:

```
formstyle:=fsStayOnTop;
borderstyle:=bsNone;
WindowState:=wsMaximized;
TransparentColor:=true;
TransparentColorValue:=clOlive;
Color:=clOlive;
```

Comment: I guess we could try to build your program and investigate. But certainly I'd be worried that I built a different program from yours and thus was debugging the wrong thing. What happens next is that you say, "oh no, my program isn't like that, it does this".  And so it goes. It might not happen this way, but so many times it does. If you provided a [mcve] then that scenario would be impossible.

Comment: thanks @DavidHeffernan for reply..  its very simple application, just set up the transparency, one button for minimize and exit..  and mainform.Canvas.Pen.Color:=clyellow;  formstyle is fsmaximized, and added one event:  Tmainform.FormClick(Sender: TObject);  what does the following: p(TPoint)  p.x:=mouse.cursorpos.x; p.y:=mouse.cursorpos.y;   mainform.Canvas.PenPos:=p; mainform.canvas.lineto(p.x,p.y);  so  - the whole program is based on drawing "dots" , lines to the desktop.  The reason - it will be helper to teachers, they can mark and draw to the desktop without affecting icons etc...)

Comment: You know what, I don't think I will. If you can't find the motivation to add a [mcve] to the question, I cannot.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan - whole code was added to the question...

Answer (score 0):

The big problem with your code is that you paint in the wrong place. You need to paint in response to a Windows paint message, `WM_PAINT`. In the context of a VCL application that typically means in an overridden `Paint` method, or an `OnPaint` event handler.

In order to paint on a form you can handle the form's `OnPaint` event and do the painting there. This will mean that you need to remember each click that is made on the form, and when you are asked to paint the window, you paint something for each click that has happened thus far.

This is a common mistake. A window does not have a persistent drawing canvas. The window must be capable of painting itself at any point in time, on demand. I suggest that you read an introductory tutorial to Win32 graphics. You could do worse than to start with Petzold's book.

Comment: thanks for answer, but it still not solving the problem with different behavior of transparent window on win8 without visual effects vs win7 with aero..  Form.click works on win8 , but not on win7 with aero.

Comment: OK, well perhaps you should ask about that then, and not confuse the matter by painting in an `OnClick` event handler. Could you edit the question accordingly. Pay proper respect to the M in MCVE. The code in the question does not make any mention of VCL styles either. I don't think you are trying hard enough to ask a precise question.

Comment: I think the question was clear enough and I cant describe my problem more, because my english skills.  If You can help me, then suggest something, if You cannot help me, dont blame my "programming" and language skills

Comment: Perhaps you are right. Perhaps I don't know what I'm talking about. Perhaps I don't know what makes a good question here. Good luck. Maybe somebody else will be able to reproduce your program.

Comment: I have to say, Delphi needs all the newbies it can get and whilst I appreciate the intent to "help someone learn to help themselves", the attitude on display here does not help encourage people into the fold one little bit.

Comment: @deltics recruiting Delphi users is not my goal

Answer (score 0):

> When I tested this mini application on windows 7 with visual styles,
>   form transparency was ignored, i was unable to draw, my mouse cursor
>   "touched" icons and objects "behind" the mainform.

With Windows 7 and Aero theme on, the form is transparent but reacts to mouse clicks, and therefore drawing works. Mouse clicks (or movement) did not go through the form to whatever is beneath the form.

With Windows 7 and Aero theme turned off, the form is transparent also for mouse actions, and subsequently drawing doesn't work and mouse actions acts on whatever is beneath the form.

So there is a difference, but it is unclear for me what you want to have.

Maybe your issue is your Windows setup? See http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/283-transparency-enable-disable.html

Answer (score -1):

Thanks for reply, i tried to change windows setup, but i want to make universal application...  So I made a frame and placed into the form, and set up `AlphaBlend` to True, and value of `AlphaBlend` set up to 1 (very ver transparent :) )..   It worked for me on Windows 7, Windows 8, 8.1 and also in windows 10...  Its not nice solution, but at least worked...